# I have been to [place] + Adverbial Phrase of Time

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect

Can we use present perfect tense to imply that we have been to [some place] before (but we are in a different place now) by adding the information that shows how long we stayed there?

But I have learnt that the sentence below is grammatically wrong:

> 1. I have been to London for two weeks.

Should I say:

> 2. I stayed in London for two weeks last month.

Comment: Both sentences look okay to me. :) -- Consider: *"I have been to the moon for two weeks. That's why I qualify for the prize."* It is often context that determines whether a sentence is acceptable or not.

Comment: While the first isn't incorrect, present perfect is a bit awkward for what you are expressing.  I suggest "I spent two weeks in [place]."

Answer (score 4):

We don't normally use the present perfect when we indicate a definite period that the event occurred at:

- *I have been to London in 1990.

But it is fine to say *how long* we were doing something for, as long as we don't indicate when this was:

- I have held my breath for three minutes before.

Notice that in the sentence above, we do not know *when* this event occurred.

The Original Poster's example sentence is grammatical, although without more context it may seem a bit odd. Here is a similar sentence with some context:

- I know you've been to London for the odd day before. But have you ever spent any *real* time there? **Have you ever been there for two weeks, for example?**

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: +1. What about *"I have already been to London in 1990. So I don't need to go there now."* :)

Comment: Yes @F.E. inserting adverbs can greatly affect the sense of the present perfect, as in *I've just been to London in 1990; I don't want to go again now* (spoken, say, in 1991) or *I've only been to London in 1990*. Although I would be apt to judge your sentence as ungrammatical--unless spoken in 1990.

Comment: @Araucaria: Leaving out the "to" from 'have been *to*' + place-name changes things quite a lot. And in your example, the time-phrase really means "for *as long as* two-weeks". Big difference. It's not a specific|definite time-period in the past.

Comment: @F.E. Yes, I was thinking about your present perfect + yesterday examples from H&P when I wrote *usually* ;) I still find them very marginal to my BE ear though - and wonder how many examples they actually found. But I'm willing to bow to their superior judgement! :-)

Comment: @TRomano Unless it's the use of the present perfect indicating something that started in the past and is continuing now, *for* always indicates a period, not a specific time. (Even in the ohter construction, it's the Present Perfect, not the *for* which enables us to get the *still going on/still not going on* reading.

Comment: @Araucaria: I understand that: I wrote "definite time-*period*".  I'm making a distinction between an actual two-week period in the past and "some period of time at least two weeks in length". There's a difference vis-a-vis the present-perfect. In your example, the phrase "for two weeks" does not refer to an actual, definite, particular "two-week" time-span but to an indefinite period of time at least two weeks in length. ("I know you've been there for the odd day...but have you ever been there [for a longer stay] for two weeks, for example").

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is grammatical. As usual, one needs to consider context. Sentences are not spoken in a void. And they are not laboratory specimens to be dissected without regard to context.

The **reason**

> I have been to London for two weeks

might *seem* ungrammatical is the following:

The basic meaning of *I've been to a place (before)* is that at some point in the past I went to a place but I am *not* still there at the moment of speaking.

> I've been to London *(before now)*

is equivalent to

> I've /gone to and returned from/ London *(before now)*

The speaker is not still in London. This can be because the speaker has gone to London and (a) returned to the starting point, or (b) went somewhere else. The *before now* is not necessary; I include it just to bring out the sense of the present perfect.

When we use the present perfect with **for a specific duration**, we *usually* do so to indicate the duration of an action begun in the past that continues to the moment of speaking, whether referring to a single continuous action, as in

> I've read this book *for two hours*, and now I am putting it away and doing something else.

Or to a series of repeated actions:

> I've read this book *for two months* and I still haven't finished it.

Since *for two hours/months* indicates the duration of an action or repeated action up to the moment of speaking

> ?I've been to London for two weeks

in the sense

> ?I've /gone to and returned from/ London for two weeks.

seems ungrammatical, since the speaker is not still in the process of /going to and returning from/ London.

However, the speaker is (still) in the state of *been to London for some **past** duration*.

CONTEXT 1
If we were discussing *how long* a person has *been to* a certain place, either on one occasion or across more than one instance, the following questions are all valid:

> Has anyone (ever) been to London *for more than a week*?

or even the more specific

> Has anyone (ever) been to London *for two weeks*?

Note the *ever* is not necessary. One can ask those same to questions without *ever* and they mean the same. I include it just to show that the question is asking about a 
We can drop *ever* and ask about a very specific *past time*:

> Has anyone been to London *for two weeks* during this past month?

For any of the above questions, the following response is grammatical:

> I've been to London for two weeks.

This is grammatical, even though the speaker is not still in London and we are using *for a duration*. This is because the speaker, at the moment of speaking, is *in the state of 'been to London' in the past.

This is also the meaning with the participle:

> Having been to London for two weeks, I can (from my experience) say that it rains a lot.

CONTEXT 2
The question

> Where have you been (recently)?

can elicit the grammatical response

> I've been to London for two weeks

---

Last, with the present perfect, we can use **just** to indicate the immediate past:

> I've just been to London

which means

> I've been to London just recently (or just now)

Adding a duration is fine:

> I've just been to London for two weeks

which means

> I've been to London for two weeks just recently (or just now)

Of course, 'just' can mean "simply" rather than "recently", as in

> I've just been to London for two weeks (I haven't done anything else)

as in:

> I've (just/simply) been to London for two weeks; I did't do anything nefarious such as engage in drug smuggling during my trip.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say:

**I have been to the moon for two weeks.**

But we *can* say:

**I haven't been to the moon for two weeks.**

At the moment, I must leave, but will complete this answer later in the day.

*I'm back.  I appreciate the forbearance. Expected to see a -10.*

The verb 'been to' can be paraphrased as 'have gone to' or 'have taken a trip to' or 'have seen' or 'have spent time in' or 'have visited'. Clearly, when it means 'have seen' or 'have gone to see' or 'have taken a trip to', we cannot have a time-expression like "for two weeks"; the question becomes hazier when it means 'spent time in|on' or 'visited'.

**I've been to the new panda exhibit for two weeks.**
(not OK: translation: ?)

**I've been to the new stadium for two weeks.**
(not OK: translation:?)

*Your cough sounds bad. Have you been to the hospital?*
--**I have been to the hospital for two weeks.**
(not OK.)

*Have you ever been to the top floor of this building?*
--**I've been to the top floor for two weeks.** 
(not OK, or at least not idiomatic. One would say *there* if one wanted to say that one is there now and had been there for the past two weeks.)

**I've been to this restaurant for two weeks.**
(not OK).

**I've been to London for the day|week.**
(OK. translation: I recently spent the day|week in London or "I have just come back from London where I spent the day|week").

*Have you been to Crete?*
--**I've been to Crete for two weeks**
(not an idiomatic reply, IMO. marginally grammatical).

**I've been to this hotel for a week.**
(not idiomatic but perhaps marginally grammatical if we understand 'been to' loosely to mean 'stayed in')

In Stangdon's example 'been to' can be paraphrased 'have visited'. (I'm moving "only" to a different location in the sentence to disentangle it from the verb.)  *"I've been to London only for one day, but I've been to Paris for two weeks"*

**I have visited London only for a day but I have visited Paris for two weeks.**

What is it about this sentence that strikes my ear as ungrammatical? It's the use of the present perfect with a *defined, finite time-span in the past*.  The action was completed in the past, so my ear wants the simple past, but there is no simple past version of 'have been to'.

The discordant time-aspect of "I have been to Paris for two weeks" is partially muted by the first clause:

*I've been to London for only one day, ...*

where "only" in "only one day" casts the time-span as *brevity*.

Comment: I disagree, but I am very curious to hear your explanation.  "I've only been to London for one day, but I've been to Paris for two weeks" sounds unremarkable to my (Northeastern US) ear.

Comment: It's a useful point to make. In example #2, *for two weeks* would normally be understood to mean ***during the past two weeks*** (with the strong implication that I've been to the moon several times, most recently two weeks ago - and further implication that I *normally* go to the moon more than once every two weeks). But whether in a negated context or not, it's grammatically/semantically possible to interpret *for two weeks* as defining the length of time I was on the moon (or not, as the case may be).

Comment: Hmmm: "I know you've been to London for the odd day. Have you ever been there fore two weeks?" <---- Seems ok to me ...

Comment: If the total time that Neil Armstrong spent on the moon was two weeks, either on one trip or as calculated across more than one trip, he can say *I have been to the moon for two weeks.*

Comment: @δοῦλος: how would you paraphrase 'been to' in that example? As "traveled to"? Or as 'spent time on'?

Comment: I do not think it is a matter of 'have been to'. The construction is appropriate for many situations. We can say "I've gone without a shower now for 6 days." OR "I've stood in line for over 24 hours, once, for tickets to Bon Jovi."

Comment: The temporal construction "for n days|weeks|months|years" is very common indeed. But the question is whether, and if so, under what circumstances, it can be used with "have been to {some place} {for n time-units}'.